# can I remotely access pages in a wampserver installed in a laptop

Tags: php, apache

I installed WampServer 3.0.4 in a laptop (I'm studying) and I have a standard internet connection from a local ISP.

I'm developing pages that I want to check from other laptops at home. I did it once but it stopped working.

I tried the following:

**In httpd.conf:**

```
Listen 80

ServerName localhost:80 (I tried <My IP Address>:80) 

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">

...

Require all granted

</Directory>
```

**In phpmyadmin.conf:**

```
Allow from all
```

**In Windows Firewall:**

I created an inbound rule in the firewall for port 80, allowing all connections for all programs

I also tried using other port like 8080, but it didn't work either

What could I be missing?

Comment: Make sure you're using the public IP of your system and not the private IP (starting with 192.168 ...) while trying to access the site from remote system.

Comment: @Shishir he only needs to use the public IP if the other computers are not located on the same network as the local "server"

Comment: If you are in the same private net, you should have no problems to display the page. Make a test disabling the firewall in your server.

Comment: @Epodax My bad. From the question, I got an impression that he's trying to access the site from home and his server setup is elsewhere.

Comment: No problems @Shishir I got confused at first as well. - Rafael, things like these don't just "stop" working, there's been a change that has caused your problems, if you made any recent changes try reverting those and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. How can I discover what is my private IP. I'm using the one that starts with 192.168. I don't have any server, I'm at home, I only have my machines connected to internet and I built a lan.